# How i can authentication on steam site?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, steam

I try to login on steam using the following code.

`steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey` first request is successful.

Request a `steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/` all the time gives an error `incorrect login.`

Perhaps dealing with encryption password or need to add ssl.

I use to encrypt library on `http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/`

```
function geturl($url, $ref, $cookie, $postdata, $header, &$info, &$output)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36');
        if ($ref)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
        }
        if ($cookie)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
        }

        if ($postdata)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            $postStr = "";
            foreach ($postdata as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($postStr)
                    $postStr .= "&";
                $postStr .= $key . "=" . $value;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postStr);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
geturl("https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey", null, null, array('username' => $login), 0, $info, $output);
$data = json_decode($output, true);

if ($data['success'] === true)
{
    $publickey_exp = $data['publickey_exp'];
    $publickey_mod = $data['publickey_mod'];
    $RSA = new Crypt_RSA();
    $RSA->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
    $n = new Math_BigInteger($publickey_mod, 16);
    $e = new Math_BigInteger($publickey_exp, 16);

    $key = array("modulus"=>$n, "publicExponent"=>$e);
    $RSA->loadKey($key, CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
    $encryptedPassword = base64_encode($RSA->encrypt($password, false));
    $captchaGid = -1;
    $captchaText;
    $emailAuth;
    $emailSteamId;

        $params = array(
            'username' => $login,
            'password' => $encryptedPassword,
            'rsatimestamp' => $data['timestamp'],
            'captcha_gid' => $captchaGid,
            'captcha_text' => $captchaText,
            'emailauth' => $emailAuth,
            'emailsteamid' => $emailSteamId
        );
        geturl("https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/", null, null, $params, 0, $info, $output);
        $data = json_decode($output, true);
        var_dump($data);
        if ($data['captcha_needed'])
        {
            $captchaGid = $data['captcha_gid'];
            echo '<img src="https://steamcommunity.com/public/captcha.php?gid=' . $captchaGid . '">';
        }
}
```

Comment: steam has several API's, any other automated access attempt is a breach of there terms

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use third-part libraries to auth.
Check this one: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

It creates login button like "Sign in via Facebook".

EDIT: Steam has alsow his own API https://steamcommunity.com/dev

Comment: I know about authentication through openid on the site, but I need to login steam through my login and password.

Comment: The problem is that the Steam API can hardly be called an API. It doesn't allow the querying of data in even half their system, especially older parts of system that you would think would be easy (such as groups and comments, not the game hubs or friend activity).

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but it looks like you are attempting to log a user into your site using Steam as the login method. Is this what you are attempting to do? If so, I recommend using the [LightOpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) library.

```
<?php
require 'includes/lightopenid/openid.php';
$_STEAMAPI = "YOURSTEAMAPIKEY";
try 
{
    $openid = new LightOpenID('http://URL.TO.REDIRECT.TO.AFTER.LOGIN/');
    if(!$openid->mode) 
    {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) 
        {
            $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid/?l=english';    // This is forcing english because it has a weird habit of selecting a random language otherwise
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_small.png">
</form>
<?php
    } 
    elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') 
    {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } 
    else 
    {
        if($openid->validate()) 
        {
                $id = $openid->identity;
                // identity is something like: http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561197960435530
                // we only care about the unique account ID at the end of the URL.
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
                echo "User is logged in (steamID: $matches[1])\n";
// $matches[1] is the profile ID you will want to use for additional API calls

        } 
        else 
        {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }
    }
} 
catch(ErrorException $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

At the end of this login, you will have the user's profile ID (ie. `76561197960435530`) which you can use against many of the [API's that Steam provides](https://steamcommunity.com/dev) to gather further information on the player.

Comment: No, I mean many, @NobleUplift. Feel free to click each of those 4 to see all the additional API calls associated with each.

Comment: Following the TeamFortress 2 wiki, there are 8 interfaces and 26 methods, which is better than the unorganized mess on the Steam wiki. There are still no API calls for querying _user interaction_ such as profile comments, or all the facets of a group including but not limited to the comments, the announcements, the comments on announcements, the group history, the forums, etc. I mean what's the point of GetUserGroupList?

Answer (score 0):

Use `"urlencode()"` function

```
$encryptedPassword = urlencode(base64_encode($RSA->encrypt($password, false)));
```