# Steam Password Encryption

Tags: php, rsa, steam

I'm trying to send a login request to Steam, in order to retrieve a session ID and other cookies however, I'm having trouble encrypting the Steam account's password correctly.

I don't really understand how this RSA stuff works, here's an example of it working (apparently). https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/php-steamlogin/blob/master/main.php If you see the `login()` method. They use a couple of libraries to do it.

I'm wondering if there's an easier way? And preferably a PHP 7/7.1 way (as the above example does lots of deprecated methods).

**EDIT:**
No idea if this is of any use, but when logging into Steam, a request it made to `https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/` with two parameters: `username` and `donotcache`. A response is then given with the following:

```
"success": true
"publickey_mod": "xxx"
"publickey_exp": "010001"
"timestamp": "1029970100000"
"token_gid": "xxx"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i can authentication on steam site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749711/how-i-can-authentication-on-steam-site)

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - No, that's using Steam as a way of authenticating. I just need to make a dummy request in order to grab a session ID and the cookies.

Comment: Can't you use the same methods to get your login request to work? You stated that you had trouble getting the password-hashing to work correctly, and that thread seems to have the correct way of making that work.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - the answers recommend using OpenID, which I can't use. I may be able to work on what he tried though, in regards to using RSA. I'll try later tonight and post my findings.